# Unity project exported to android project exception (Multiple dex files define Lcom/qualcomm/QCARUnityPlayer/BuildConfig)

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, buildconfig

I exported the project from unity 4D to Android project but when i run it iget this error

Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/qualcomm/QCARUnityPlayer/BuildConfig;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/qualcomm/QCARUnityPlayer/BuildConfig;

I did change the Project -> properties to include the Android 4.2.2 and Android Dependencies but i still not able to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the exported project (from Unity) has the same package name "com.qualcomm/QCARUnityPlayer" as one defined in QCARUnityPlayer.jar.

Please take the steps as I did it successfully.

1) Create your activity that extends QCARPlayerNativeActivity

```
    package com.example.unitytest;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARPlayerNativeActivity;

    public class MyUnityAR extends QCARPlayerNativeActivity{

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("Test", "MyUnityAR is running.");
      }
    }
```

2) Modify AndroidManifest.xml

> < manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="**com.example.unitytest**" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
>   
> ...
>     < application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
>   
>     < activity android:name="**.MyUnityAR**" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >

3) Clean and Build, then enjoy.

**Reference**: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/extending-unity-android-activity-and-adding-custom-views-eclipse